# Directing USB webcam into RTSP server or MJPEG server (OS X)

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, webcam, video-streaming, rtsp

I have - for want of a better term - a DVR, which accepts IP camera feeds in the form of RTSP streams or MJPEG feeds. It works a treat.

For reasons I'll not go into, for the sake of a customer demo, I'd like also to feed the DVR with the output from the webcam onboard my MacBook (which is effectively, I believe, a USB webcam).

So I'm here to ask if anyone has ever successfully served up their webcam via RTSP or MJPEG? I'm looking for personal experience because there is a fair amount of information on the web about doing this with VLC but I've not for the life of me been able to make it work. The input side works fine (accessing the device) but I can't get the RTSP side working, and the VLC manual on the topic just contains an apology for the absence of any documentation. Maybe it being on a mac is the fly in the ointment. Am very open to alternative approaches too so if anyone anything to suggest it would be very welcome. Thank you all!